# Cold Weather Trees with Buttress Roots?

Tags: trees, cold-weather

Are there cold-weather trees with buttress roots which would grow well in the Northeast of the US?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Dawn Redwood (*Metasequoia glyptostroboides*)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metasequoia_glyptostroboides) has buttress roots, and can survive in USDA zones 4-8.

[image] ([image source](https://trees.umn.edu/news/featured-tree-dawn-redwood-metasequoia-glyptostroboides))

[image] ([image source](http://www.finegardening.com/plant/metasequoia-glyptostroboides))

Comment: Thanks, any others offhand?  Or non-conifers in general?  Also, do you know of any databases to look up things like trees with specific types of roots (buttress/aerial/etc) for specific zones like the north east?

Comment: No others come to mind. Buttress roots seem to be more of a tropical phenomenon, and certainly most descriptions that come up when googling "buttress roots" refer to rainforests and/or the tropics. They seem most necessary in areas with lots of rain, to add new support when the soil washes away.

Comment: Some beech trees have some impressive tangles of roots, although I've never heard them called buttress roots. You could have a look at some images and see if that fills the same aesthetic niche for you.

Comment: Maine has a ton of rain, and I'm actually planning on using these in a very large (1-2 acre) marsh filtration system for a pond to give it a deeply wetland-like-without-the-bugs look - though that's definitely the issue I've run into as well while searching - buttress and aerial roots seem mostly confined to warmer/tropical climates - I assume due to the complex topology making them prone to breakage during frosts.